# libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend - React Native iOS - How do I read this crash report?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, crash, react-native-ios

My React Native iOS app is randomly crashing with this, and I do not know how to interpret it. Any ideas as to what it means?

EDIT: If this is a bad question, please let me know where I can help on this, as I do not know where to begin looking. It's a random crash that has been bugging me for a while now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome-debugger. That should help you tracking the cause of the crash. Also you need to draw the pattern out of the randomness. The image you have sent was not helpful enough to me to understand the problem.

If you do not know how to use the chrome-debugging, this might help : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: The problem with this crash is that it doesn't hit the chrome debugger or show an error. It just closes the app and leaves me with nothing.

Comment: Well, I need more details to help you out.