# CRASHED UIKit : _prepareForCAFlush

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, crash, uikit

I have an issue with my app, a "NSInternalInconsistencyException" is thrown. According to Crashlytics, the function that triggers this is **_prepareForCAFlush**.

Unfortunately,  we are unable to detect what could be the problem (the bug can't be reproduced). Has anybody encounter this kind of crash? Here's the stack trace.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1e140df7 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1d3a3077 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1e140cd1 +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x1ea3b987 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKit                          0x23465ea1 _prepareForCAFlush
5  UIKit                          0x2348347f _beforeCACommitHandler
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1e0fbf15 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1e0fa191 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1e0fa5a7 __CFRunLoopRun
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1e049533 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1e049341 CFRunLoopRunInMode
11 GraphicsServices               0x1f820bfd GSEventRunModal
12 UIKit                          0x23251e67 -[UIApplication _run]
13 UIKit                          0x2324c591 UIApplicationMain
14 App                            0xc4d9a4 main (AppDelegate.swift:22)
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1d81350b (Missing)
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you ever solved this?

Comment: This seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702417/ios-9-crashing-in-prepareforcaflush-with-exc-bad-access-kern-invalid-address